# How to correctly set permisions for all subfolders and files

Tags: permissions, chown, tinyos

I am following [the guide to install `TinyOS` on Ubuntu 12.04](http://jenis23.blogspot.nl/2012/05/install-tinyos-under-ubuntu-1204.html)

I have done up to step 3, But I am not sure if I have done the step 3 correctly. Because by doing the step 4 I get the permission error :

```
saeid@saeid-Satellite-C660:~$ tos-install-jni
/usr/bin/tos-install-jni: 13: [: =: unexpected operator
Installing 32-bit Java JNI code in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386 ... 
install: cannot create regular file `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libgetenv.so': Permission denied
```

Can you please tell me what would be the actual commands for step 3? What I have to replace with following lines?:

- /opt/tinyos-2.x files: chown -R  /opt/tinyos-2.x
- Change the permissions on any serial (/dev/ttyS), usb (/dev/tts/usb, /dev/ttyUSB), or parallel (/dev/parport) devices you are going to use: chmod 666 /dev/

I mean how would you do those steps in your ubuntu?

Comment: How did you run the 3rd step please post. In fourth step use `sudo tos-install-jni`

Comment: @ManulaWaidyanatha please post your comment as answer so that he can accept it and the question can be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use command `sudo tos-install-jni` to avoid permission denied error.